# Select2 - style highlighted term in result

Tags: css, jquery-select2

By default select2 underlines the matching term in the search results.

[image]

Is there a way to style this if I wanted the matching term to be **BOLD** or coloured instead of underlined?  I would assume so, but I can't find anything in the docs or on the internet about this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the formatResult function, heres is some relevant reading
https://github.com/iStefo/ember-select-2/issues/109
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/select2/FhVygJ_21Nk

here is an example of what I use in one of my implementations for custom format result , where I encapsulate results in tags that I style using css

```
formatResult: function(result, container, query, escapeMarkup) {
        var markup=[];
        window.Select2.util.markMatch(result.text, query.term, markup, escapeMarkup);
        if (result.isNew) {
            return markup.join("");
        } else {
            return '<span class="post-tag">'+markup.join("")+'</span><span class="item-multiplier">×&nbsp;'+result.count+'</span>';
        }

    },
```